# How to test, if RecordType exists (in production org)

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a function that simply queries the Id of a specific `RecordType` by its name:

```
private static Id getLeadRecordTypeIdByName(String sRecordTypeName) {
    return schema.SObjectType.Lead.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(sRecordTypeName).getRecordTypeId();
}
```

In my code I invoke this function with different RecordTypeNames, e.g. 'Customer', 'Partner', to create the respective Leads with their `RecordTypes`. Obviously, this code will work, as long as the `RecordTypes` exist in the production org.

Now I want to build a test case, that succeeds as long as the recordtypes exist, e.g. the unittest should verify, that the `getLeadRecordTypeIdByName` will yield a valid RecordTypeId and no `null` or error.

How do I write the specific test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test itself is simple to write:

```
static testMethod void testGetLeadRecordTypeIdByName()
{
    RecordType abitraryType = [
        SELECT Name FROM RecordType
        WHERE SObjectType = 'Lead' LIMIT 1
    ];

    Test.startTest();
        Id result = MyClass.getLeadRecordTypeIdByName(arbitraryType.Name);
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(arbitraryType.Id, result, 'The correct Id should be returned');
}
```

Note the assertion that verifies your method does what it claims to do. Take a look at [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests), which has a lot of good advice.

You should also test the case where the name does *not* match. Right now, the method will throw a `NullPointerException`, which is generally undesirable behavior. I would refactor to include a null check, but either way, you should **test the negative case as well**. A more null-safe method would check if the `RecordTypeInfo` exists before calling `getRecordTypeId`.

```
public static Id getLeadRecordTypeIdByName(String name)
{
    RecordTypeInfo info = SObjectType.Lead.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(name);
    return (info == null) ? null : info.getRecordTypeId();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the refactoring of my original function. However, what happens if the recordtype doesn not exists? The arbitraryType.id will be `null` and the result will be equally `null`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JannisLietzau Your `arbitraryType` would never be `null`. If you do not even have a single `RecordType` defined on the `Lead` object, it will throw a `QueryException` instead. As long as you have at least one `RecordType` defined, it will pass.

Comment: ok, I got it. Since the test fails if my expected RecordTypes don't exist on the executing org, this is fine. Thank you a lot!